# Concatenating the first n semiprimes (in order) to get a semiprime $469101415$...

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, semiprimes

The concatenation of the first $1,2,3,6,43$, and $61$ semiprimes (in order) is a semiprime (!),

- $4=2 . 2$
- $46=2 . 23$
- $469=7 . 67$
- $469101415=5 . 93820283$
- $4691014152122....121122123129$ (proven semiprime,though no factors are known)
- $46910141521222526....183185187=108525583p$. (p is prime)

  After these I don't find anymore such semiprime up to the first $350$ semiprimes. My question: Is there anymore semiprime of such form ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you know the last two concatenations are semiprimes?  In particular, what algorithm shows that a number has exactly two factors without explicitly finding them?

Comment: @BarryCipra , p there means a prime. And I say it proven semiprime because I saw it at one site titled  _prime curios_at $34$+ page.

Comment: And yes, there's an algorithm for semiprimeness test (!), but I forget the connection, but I believe I also saw it at oeis. Incredibly this algorithm can determine whether a $5000$ digit number is a semiprime or not, without mentioning the factors at all (!!) : )

Comment: I assume the link you mean is https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php?curio_id=11492 .  It would help a lot if you explained how *you* go about testing for semiprimeness (although I assume most concatenations get ruled out because they're divisible by a couple of small primes).

Comment: I just checked it manually with my laptop using online prime number calculator, and yes most of them divisible by small primes, especially primes below $1000$.

Comment: Um, I just checked, and I get $1085255831 = 11*751*131371$.  Is there a typo in that number?

Comment: The two factors of $46910\dots129$ are $561142648578701032870967$ and $83597533782255928599777933064811804102379251037232937344874950747087$